# Setting attributed label as navigation title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel

I am working on IOS using swift 4. I have to make the Navigation controller, with the center Aligned App title with Image at its left. But I am not getting how to attach image to its left. The attributed Image always goes to its right.

For this I am appending the string twice. below is the code

```
   //Get image and set it's size
    let image = UIImage(named: "user2")
    let newSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

    //Resize image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let imageResized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Create attachment text with image
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = imageResized
    let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
    myString.append(attachmentString)
    let strAttachment = NSAttributedString(string: "My Ios App" )
    myString.append(strAttachment)

    navLabel.attributedText = myString

    self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel
```

What I am getting is some thing like below image is on left
[image]

**what I want :**

I just want the image to be shown with the space between text and Image.
I want the image to be look good and nice. Text should be center vertically to the image. what is good way of achieving this ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using this code you will get your output :**

```
        let navgationView = UIView()

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = " My Ios App"
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.center = navgationView.center
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = UIImage(named: "user")
        let imageAspect = image.image!.size.width/image.image!.size.height
        image.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x-label.frame.size.height*imageAspect, y: label.frame.origin.y, width: label.frame.size.height*imageAspect, height: label.frame.size.height)
        image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

        navgationView.addSubview(label)
        navgationView.addSubview(image)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = navgationView
        navgationView.sizeToFit()
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Hope it's helps.!!

Comment: There is no horizontal space , How ever the idea of setting image with the equal height of text is good

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust your attachment position you must use the `attachment.bounds` property and if you want to adjust the text vertical alignment you need to use `NSAttributedString` `baselineOffset` key

**Update**

**Swift 3 code**

```
        let normalNameString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "")

        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = imageHelper.pgImage(textValue: "PG-13")
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (attachment.image?.size.width)!, height: (attachment.image?.size.height)!)
        normalNameString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
        normalNameString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " My Ios App", attributes: [NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName :6]))
        self.lblText.attributedText = normalNameString
```

**Swift 4 code**

```
        let normalNameString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "")

        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = imageHelper.pgImage(textValue: "PG-13")
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (attachment.image?.size.width)!, height: (attachment.image?.size.height)!)
        normalNameString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
        normalNameString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " My Ios App", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset :6]))
        self.lblText.attributedText = normalNameString
```

**Swift 5 Update**

```
    let normalNameString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "")

    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = imageHelper.pgImage(textValue: "PG-13")
    attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (attachment.image?.size.width)!, height: (attachment.image?.size.height)!)
    normalNameString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
    normalNameString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " My Ios App", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset :6]))
    self.lblText.attributedText = normalNameString
```

[image]

Comment: I want to adjust a space between text and image and text should be center vertically. Please show me code

Comment: but you have given space using space in text. Is there any other way to give  space ? and also tell me what should be image preferred size

Comment: You can achieve the same effect by changing the attachment bounds x with a negative value also @Androidteem, adding an space in the text is easiest