# Swift: Mix fontawesome icon with string in UIbutton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, font-awesome

I am using `FontAwesome.swift` in Swift 5 to add a fontawesome icon to my UIbutton. I want to mix fontawesome icon with a String, `"Database"`. Here is what I have tried:

```
self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 15, style: .solid)
self.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .database) + " Database", for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

However, the result gives me two identical icons:

[image]

What I want is something like this:

[image: ui]

Comment: In Github repo of this pod there is not example about what you are trying, but you can do this using Attributed String and `NSTextAttachment`, please kindly check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040115/setting-attributed-label-as-navigation-title/50040317#50040317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
let str = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .database) + " Database"
let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)

//Apply FontAwesome to the first character
let range1 = NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)
attributedStr.addAttribute(.font,
                           value: UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 15, style: .solid),
                           range: range1)

//Apply the system font to the rest of the string
let range2 = NSRange(location: 1, length: (str as NSString).length - 1)
attributedStr.addAttribute(.font,
                           value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
                           range: range2)

//Set the attributed text for the button
self.setAttributedTitle(attributedStr, for: .normal)  //self being the button *itself*
```

And here is the result:

[image: button]

Comment: Thanks! I can't understand NSMutableAttributedString. I guess it comes from objective-c?

Comment: @BanghuaZhao correct, it is simply a mutable attributed string.

Answer (score 1):

The library search substrings in the source string and replace the corresponding icon. One of these words is "Database". Another text can be put without problems.
Such a feeling, that there is a lack of screening functionality for such situations.